# Flask for server and Node.js for API?

Tags: node.js, api, flask, server

I am currently developing a web app using Flask, while one of my peers is developing an API using Node.js. The end goal is to use the API for all database queries and I am currently posting to the API in the backend of the flask application, but I am wondering - do I still need to use Flask as a backend if we have a separate API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, having a separate application for your web app and your data API is a good idea. This is a good practice for when you want to scale up an application.

Think of it this way... your API will probably service more apps than just your web application. If you decide to build a mobile app, your web app and your mobile app will consume data from the same API, but serve different users. Your web and mobile apps are handling two different pools of users, but your API is handling all of them. Therefore, your API will probably scale up faster than your mobile or web application services.

If your data API and your web app are the same application, you would have to scale them up as one service even though your web app might not be the core contributor to API traffic.

Comment: Thanks Max! To be more specific: right now, my web app queries the database directly and displays the results using jinja, but posts new data using the api. It feels sort of redundant right now that the client submits a form to the server, the server parses the data, and then re-submits that data to the api. Is this a bad way to go about this, or should i continue and re-route get requests through the api as well?

Comment: @LandonMarshall I would suggest that your peer's node app would have a route that your Flask app would hit to request the data. Two reasons, first your data API app should dictate the structure of the data and parse it into that structure. That way every app that is consuming the data is not parsing the data over and over again. Secondly, you want your data API app to be the only app querying the database so that you know where and when your database is being queried. For performance and security.

Comment: @LandonMarshall as for the form submission that's not a bad way to go about it. You could hit your data API if you want. That's really up to you guys. Just make sure you sanitize the form data

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you're using for your front end, if you're using some kind of javascript framework (Angular, React) you can just make the API calls from the client side.

But since you haven't mentioned those it sounds like you're just using Flask's template engine (Jinja) which is a server side template system. So you'll still be using Flask on the backend to build the templates.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't/shouldn't still use an API layer.

Comment: I didn't say he shouldn't use an API layer, just that it would be getting called by Flask, which is also a part of the backend